# How to disable refresh button once user goes on a particular web page?

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I have to create a web page for a online quiz which will display same questions in different sequence for each user. 
Now, I have written code which takes questions randomly every time when user visit that page. User goes to that page by login id and password.
I have used random function in query which gives questions in different order for each user. But now problem is when i refresh that page question order changes for the same user. 
So i wants to disable refresh button. Can you please tell me how to disable it? or is there any other way?

Comment: if you have been visited any secured site like banking site - what they did - they've not disabled the refresh button, but instead warn user if he refresh the page - it will be the end !

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to disable refresh button.

You can try to save questions order in users session and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the button. You shouldn't be messing with the user's browser.

What you can do however, is to show a dialog asking the user if they want to leave the page.

```
<body onbeforeunload="return 'Are you sure you want to leave the page?';">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate and store question order once per session or login instead of on every request.